# Unable to Drag and drop into iframe using cypress

Tags: cypress

Hi I have to drag a component which is outside a frame and drop into a iframe body(dragable source)
but it is not draging my component into iframe dragable source

this is code which is am using for get into the iframe and it is working means it is going into the iframe and finding element

```
const getIframeDocument = () => {
  return cy.get(".gjs-frame").its("0.contentDocument").should("exist");
};

const getIframeBody = () => {
  // get the document
  return (
    getIframeDocument()
      // automatically retries until body is loaded
      .its("body")
      .should("not.be.undefined")
      // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
      // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
      .then(cy.wrap)
  );
};
```

and 
 for drag and drop into iframe like this

```
getIframeBody().find("#wrapper").as("Target");
cy.get('[title="Url"]').drag("@Target");
```

this is not giving me any error this drag function working but at the same time drag and drop is not happening
[drag and drop execution pic must see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5OBB.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using this code. You just need to change selectors according to your website.

// Define Locators.

```
drag_element = '.blockbuilder-content-tools .blockbuilder-content-tool:nth- 
child(6)';
drop_element = '#u_body #u_row_2';
text_indentation = '[aria-label="Align center"]';
```

new_box_text = 'This is a new Text block. Change the text.'

// Get iframe body and then drag & drop element.

```
iframe_interaction(){
    let ifm = cy.get('iframe');
    ifm
       .should(iframe => expect(iframe.contents().find('body')))
       .then(iframe => cy.wrap(iframe.contents().find('body')))
       .within({}, $iframe => {
         cy.get(this.drag_element).drag(this.drop_element, { force: true })
         cy.contains(this.new_box_text).dblclick({force: true})
         cy.get(this.text_indentation).click()
  })
 Github Link: https://github.com/sardar-usman/Cypress--Drag-and-Drop
```